Lie derivative of a co-vector field w.r.t to vector field.
Consider a smooth manifold with a metric(Reimanian or Pseudo Riemannian) and let $X$ be a non zero vector field.
We know the Lie derivative, $L_{X} X$=0.
Let $X^\flat$ be the 1-form dual to $X$ via metric.
Then is $L_{X} X^\flat =0$?
Thank you.

Could you show us what you’ve tried so far?

I tried using Cartan's magic formula and component definition of the Lie derivative. At this point it seems there is no reason to believe $L_{X} X^\flat =0$ in general.

if $X$ is Killing, then yes. In general, see this question.

@peek-a-boo Thank you!

Working in chart coordinates, we have;
$$\mathcal{L}_X\big(X^{\flat}\big)=\mathcal{L}_X\big(\big[X^m\partial_m\big]^{\flat}\big)$$
$$=\mathcal{L}_X\big(g_{mn}X^mdx^n\big)$$
$$=\mathcal{L}_X\big(g_{mn}X^m\big)dx^n+g_{mn}X^m\mathcal{L}_X\big(dx^n\big)$$
$$=X^k\partial_k\big(g_{mn}X^m\big)dx^n+g_{mn}X^m\cdot d\big[\mathcal{L}_X\big(x^n\big)\big]$$
$$=X^k\partial_k\big(g_{mn}X^m\big)dx^n+g_{mn}X^m\big(\partial_pX^n\big)dx^p$$
$$\therefore\big[\mathcal{L}_X(X^{\flat})\big]_n=X^k\partial_k\big(g_{mn}X^m\big)+g_{mp}X^m\big(\partial_nX^p\big)$$
$$=X^mX^k\partial_k\big(g_{mn}\big)+g_{mn}X^k\big(\partial_kX^m\big)+g_{mp}X^m\big(\partial_nX^p\big)$$
So, in general, $\mathcal{L}_X\big(X^{\flat}\big)\neq0$. However, when $X$ is a Killing vector field one can easily show that the following must hold;
$$\mathcal{L}_X(g)=0 \implies X^{\gamma}\partial_{\gamma}\big(g_{\mu\nu}\big)=-\big[g_{\alpha\nu}\partial_{\mu}X^{\alpha}+g_{\mu\beta}\partial_{\nu}X^{\beta}\big]$$
Plugging this into our identity for $\big[\mathcal{L}_X(X^{\flat})\big]_n$ gives us;
$$\big[\mathcal{L}_X(X^{\flat})\big]_n=-X^m\big[g_{\alpha n}\partial_{m}X^{\alpha}+g_{m\beta}\partial_{n}X^{\beta}\big]+g_{mn}X^k\big(\partial_kX^m\big)+g_{mp}X^m\big(\partial_nX^p\big)$$
Which after some simple re-indexing yields;
$$\big[\mathcal{L}_X(X^{\flat})\big]_n=0$$
